# cannot read property name of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js. I started to learn from yesterday.

I have a form with simple file upload and submit button

**JS file**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function(req, res){

    if (req.url == '/fileupload'){
       var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.parse(req, function (err, files, fields){
           var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
           console.log(oldpath);
           var newpath = 'F:/' + files.filestoupload.name;
           console.log('Destination set!');
           fs.readFile(oldpath, function (err, data){
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('File read!');
               fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function(err){
                   if (err) throw err;
                   res.write('Package shipped and moved');
                   res.end();
                   console.log('Newpath is' + newpath);
                   });
                fs.unlink(oldpath, function (err){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Temp file deleted");
                    });
               });
           });
    } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

It somehow runs on the browser, but when I hit upload button an error pops up in the command prompt

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at F:\Prince\workspace\NODE JS\formidable.js:12:48
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (F:\Prince\workspace\NODE JS\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:107:9)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (F:\Prince\workspace\NODE JS\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:557:8)
    at QuerystringParser.parser.onEnd (F:\Prince\workspace\NODE JS\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:458:10)
    at QuerystringParser.end (F:\Prince\workspace\NODE JS\node_modules\formidable\lib\querystring_parser.js:25:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (F:\Prince\workspace\NODE JS\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:132:30)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1098:12)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
```

I'll appreciate if anyone clarifies my mistake.

Ps: read comments too.

Comment: `filestoupload` should be `filetoupload`?

Comment: Should be pretty obvious, the error is on line `var newpath = 'F:/' + files.filestoupload.name;` so use a good editor (visual studio code, sublime, etc) and highlight that `filestoupload`, then notice it's _not_ highlight anything else. Typo found.

Comment: Oops! typo. But it shows new error now `[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of the type string, Buffer, or URL.`

Comment: form.parse(req, function (err, files, fields){  
Incorrect callback format.
Correct Callback format - form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {})

Comment: @INDRESHKHANDELWAL `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging for a while I found the issues here.

There are three mistakes here.

As @Jordan S said there is an typo in line:12

*`filestoupload`* should be *`filestoupload`*

Then `Incorrect callback format` in form parse in line:10

*`form.parse(req, function (err, files, fields)`* to *`form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files)`*

And the final one is in the form `enctype` is missing

```
res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
```

adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` fixed the final issue.

But I still don't know what is the point of adding `enctype`

**Updated JS File**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if (req.url == '/fileupload'){
       var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files){
           var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
           console.log(oldpath);
           var newpath = 'F:/' + files.filetoupload.name;
           console.log('Destination set!');
           fs.readFile(oldpath, function (err, data){
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('File read!');
               fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function(err){
                   if (err) throw err;
                   res.write('Package shipped and moved');
                   res.end();
                   console.log('Newpath is' + newpath);
                   });
                fs.unlink(oldpath, function (err){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Temp file deleted");
                    });
               });
           });
    } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080);
```